# Do we always use reference type for foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As the title says, do we always use type reference for foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to.

As stated in the Rails guides:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special-helpers

> Another helper is called references (also available as belongs_to). In
>   its simplest form it just adds some readability.

Another option, in a migration you could just declare:

```
t.integer :account_id # where :account_id will hold the id being referenced to for a belongs_to
```

So for example. The rails guides examples is this:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.references :category
end
```

but you could also do this:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.integer :category_id
end
```

Comment: I see. Thank you! So is there any pros and cons for each of them?

Comment: Pro would be for readability. Con would be that it's not immediately obvious what's the column name. Personally I prefer `t.integer :category_id`